# How do I find my phase margin using the Bode plot?

Tags: control, bode-plot

[image]

From the Bode plot, is my phase margin correct? I estimate around +30 degree phase margin - or is it -30 degree phase margin? I am unsure about this thing.

Comment: Mb you're right its around 15-20

Comment: @Ashytone - Hi, To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] your question & add the document / video / webpage name & link for the source of that "Figure 1(a)" image. TY

Answer (score 1):

This is how phase margin is determined from the bode-plot: -

[image]

Image taken from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dynamicsystem.margin.html) or, maybe [this one](https://www.powerelectronictips.com/what-is-a-bode-plot-faq/) is more suitable: -

[image]

> *From the Bode plot, is my phase margin correct? I estimate around +30
> degree phase margin*

It looks more like +15° to me i.e. two-thirds of the way from -135° to -180° is where the phase pitches and, this is +15° of margin.

Comment: Comment (to Ashytone): When the phase diagram starts for low frequencies at 0 deg  (neg. sign for neg. feedback at the summing junction not taken into account), the "critical phase" for finding the margin is at -180 deg. However, when the phase function starts at -180deg (Andy akas last figure, phase inversion is taken into account) the "critical phase" is at the 0deg line. Both alternatives are in use.

Comment: Total flashback to my power supply design days. Love the Venable FRA application. (The FRAs themselves are pretty indestructible as well.)